# Javascript innerHTML not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a web application where the user drags and drops a task name, then the corresponding task name has to appear in a table.

When this happens a new row has to be added when the drop occurs.

I have used javascript for drag and drop and to add the new row.

My code works in chrome and firefox but not in IE. Why?

here is a sample of my code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var trNumber = 1;

function addTimeSheetRow(){
    var timeSheetBody = document.getElementById("timeSheetBody");
    var trow = document.createElement("tr");

    trow.innerHTML = "<th ondragstart='return false;' ondrop='return false;'></th>" +
    "<th ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' value='' class='dropTexts'></th>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Mon") + " type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Tue") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Wed") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Thu") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Fri") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Sat") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td><input name=" + getTrDayNames("Sun") + "  type='text' value='' size='2'/></td>" +
    "<td class='total'><input type='text' value='0' size='2' readonly='readonly'/></td>"; 

    timeSheetBody.appendChild(trow);

    $("tbody#timeSheetBody td input:not(.intial)").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            newSum.call(this);
            colSum.call(this);

        });
    });

    document.getElementsByName("trNumber")[0].value = trNumber;
}

function allowDrop(ev)
{
    //ev.preventDefault();
    ev.preventDefault ? ev.preventDefault() : ev.returnValue = false;
}
function drag(ev)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    //var projectElement = ev.target.parentNode;
    //ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", projectElement.getAttribute("id"));
    //alert(projectElement.getAttribute("id"));
}

function drop(ev)
{
    //ev.preventDefault();
    ev.preventDefault ? ev.preventDefault() : ev.returnValue = false;
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var taskName =document.getElementById(data).innerHTML;
    //alert(taskName);
    var trTaskName = "tr" + trNumber + "TaskName";
    ev.target.innerHTML = taskName + "<input name=" + trTaskName + " type='hidden' value='" + taskName + "' size='2' class='intial'/>";


    var projectName = document.getElementById(data).parentNode.getAttribute("id");
    //alert(projectName);
    var projectTextBox = ev.target.parentNode.children[0];
    var trProjectName = "tr" + trNumber + "ProjectName";
    projectTextBox.innerHTML = projectName + "<input name=" + trProjectName + " type='hidden' value='" + projectName + "' size='2' class='intial'/>";


    trNumber = trNumber + 1;

    addTimeSheetRow();
}
```

Comment: What version of IE? Native drag and drop only works on IE 9+

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Hard to say, but by the error type(don't working only in IE and table handling) I'd give a shot that is something related to `tbody` tags.

Comment: i tried to check errors in IE it is not recognising the <th> tags

Comment: how you kept 2 th and other td, It should be all td or th its html is not correct

Comment: @anupsharma, it's not correct. `<th>` may be the header for the row, in this case it is completely OK to have a `<th>` and several `<td>`s in one row. HTML 4 and all subsequent (X)HTML standards allow this.

Comment: okay, but you know html dont gives an errors it execute by default.... but no problem ... fine

Comment: Choose either full `createElement` or full innerHTML solution at a time.

Comment: @Liam dont edit code unnecessary .... only add when it has some issue or according to need. thanks

Comment: @anupsharma, your entire answer was formatted as code. I simply removed the unnecessary formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by making a custom .innerHTML (yes it's a lot of work) or otherwise modifying the .innerHTML property/function. I made this code to make sure that still-referenced child element data is preserved when clearing the .innerHTML (another problem with IE's .innerHTML), but it can be adapted to solve the IE tables problem.

```
if (/(msie|trident)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
 var innerhtml_get = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "innerHTML").get
 var innerhtml_set = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, "innerHTML").set
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "innerHTML", {
  get: function () {return innerhtml_get.call (this)},
  set: function(new_html) {
   var childNodes = this.childNodes
   for (var curlen = childNodes.length, i = curlen; i > 0; i--) {
    this.removeChild (childNodes[0])
   }
   innerhtml_set.call (this, new_html)
  }
 })
}

var mydiv = document.createElement ('div')
mydiv.innerHTML = "test"
document.body.appendChild (mydiv)

document.body.innerHTML = ""
console.log (mydiv.innerHTML)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DLLbc/9/

http://jsfiddle.net/DLLbc/12/

Comment: I made a change: try http://jsfiddle.net/DLLbc/12 for specific bug detection, if you don't have mutation observers loaded before this code runs. You can also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661996/fixing-ie-bugs-always-a-good-idea

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug: You can set the innerHTML of tables only when you create the table in IE. But `document.createElement` and other dom manipulations should work fine. Alternatively you could use a js lib for compatibility.

Comment: the drag and drop works, but the new row is not getting added in IE9

Comment: Hasn't this bug been fixed in IE8+? May be it's a quirks mode issue?

Comment: can you explain wat is a quirks mode issue?

Answer (score 0):

FOR NORMAL JS:

A known and no so hard to do fix is to create all elements, not to create a string with all content and add it.

The same way you created the tr, create tds, etc.

In your case might not be so nice to do because of the large structure but...

FOR A BETTER WAY OF LIVING:

Use jQuery/prototype/mootools or whatever other lib you like.

Comment: it would become a tedious job.. is there an alternative other than using innerHTML?

Comment: Native... no. As Floste said, or as I said in answer... use a lib. I suggest jQuery. Makes your life much easier. Or if you want you can create your own function to do that, and pass an array of strings (or a string if you feel like breaking it into parts) as parameters. Or maybe if you have the option just ignore IE 7 (if I remember right this is fixed in IE 8 (I'm sure about 9, not sure about 8)).