# Fixing IE bugs: always a good idea?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

Internet Explorer improved *a lot* in the last 3 years and since IE 10 has become a fairly decent browser with good performances. But, even with these improvements, web developers still have to:

1. deal with older versions, in particular IE8 or even IE7;
2. work around bugs the IE drags since *forever*, like the [unimplemented `document.evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521554/xpath-in-internet-explorer-10-gone), or `oninput` event that isn't fired on deletion or on `contentEditable` elements.

I was asking myself what's an "acceptable" limit for those workarounds. For example, IE<9 `change` event doesn't bubble up: but since it supports `focusin` and `focusout`, which do bubble, it can be fixed with a couple of event listeners.

It's also well known that IE<9 doesn't handle the `innerHTML` property on `<select>` elements properly, so we can redefine the property (IE8 only):

```
(function() {
    var re = /^<SELECT(?: [\w:]+=(?:\S+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*"))*>/,
        div = document.createElement("div");
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, "innerHTML", {get: function() {
        var out = this.outerHTML, m = out.match(re);
        return m ? out.slice(m[0].length, -9) : "";
    }, set: function(v) {
        this.innerText = "";
        if (v = String(v)) {
            div.innerHTML = "<select>" + v + "</select>";
            var s = div.firstChild;
            while (s.firstChild) this.appendChild(s.firstChild);
        }
    }});
})();
```

But IE - even IE11! - still doesn't allow to dynamically set the `value` property of a `<select>` element, so (IE8-11):

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, "value", {get: function() {
    var opt = this.selectedIndex >= 0 ? this.options[this.selectedIndex] : null;
    return opt ? opt.value : "";
}, set: function(val) {
    val = String(val);
    var ops = this.options, i = ops.length;
    while (i--) if (ops[i].value === val) break;
    this.selectedIndex = i;
}});
```

These work quite well, maybe a bit slower but just in a resticted case: `HTMLSelectElement`s. And they rarely can represent a performance issue.

But since I'm changing some basic DOM properties, I was wondering if there could be any problems that I'm not sighting. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: A good question, but probably not a good fit for SO.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're asking. If you need to support IE version X, then surely there's no choice but to make it work in that version and up. Or are you asking if it's ok to drop support for older IEs?

Comment: FYI, for your `.innerHTML` fix, it's probably better to get the property descriptor, cache the `get` in a variable, and have your new `get` call the cached one. A little cleaner than using a regex.

Comment: I don't get why this question was closed as "primarily opinion-based". I'm asking is there can be any kind of issues. It's no different than asking if it's a good idea to extend `Object.prototype`. That's hardly opinion based. How many of you have actually redefined `value`, and what problems have you faced? @Juhana I'm asking if it's better to rely on some more abstract methods like a `setValue` or `setInnerHTML` and stuff like that - which *must* be adopted in IE7 and lower. The solutions I've proposed cannot be the only ones, can they?

Comment: Your question seems to start off asking what's acceptable WRT fixing old or current IE bugs. That's a matter of opinion, and depends on a particular situation. At the end you ask about potential problems. Perhaps rephrase your question to be more focused. ...And the question of whether it's a good idea to extend `Object.prototype` is absolutely a matter of opinion.

Comment: @cookiemonster And *that* it's *your* opinion on the matter, but I beg to differ. There are known caveats that are commonly accepted, and they're clearly not opinion. Again, this question is no different. But thanks for the tip about `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Comment: I have adopted a core site model, similar to the guardian's approach. http://vimeo.com/channels/smashingconf

Comment: @MaxArt: You're right, there are very important caveats that are matters of fact. Whether or not one ultimately should extend `Object.prototype` is opinion. FWIW, I never extend it, nor do I think it's a good idea, but that's just my opinion. I think your question could be easily rephrased to focus on those areas that you're concerned about, like potential issues. But if you do, I'd try to give well-defined criteria, like IE versions you *must* support.